# jQuery .css increases length of html()

Tags: jquery, css

I'm measure length of AJAXed content vs existing one  and
,in mean time, I add background color via .css().

To measure length I use `$("#mydiv").html().length`

New content is always shorter because of the css() attribute
added.

Here's the jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/3RV8C/1/ representing that.

My work around is to use .text().

But is adding length to items a proper behavior?

**EDIT:**
To answer: I was looking for behavior of css files/or inline css.

Comment: You mean that? http://jsfiddle.net/3RV8C/2/

Comment: @A.Wolff ok thats a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're comparing:

```
<div class="inner">asdf</div>
```

versus

```
<div class="inner" style="background-color: yellow;">asdf</div>
```

What did you expect the result to be?

Comment: I guess his question is not how HTML should look like but why innerHTML is changed when object is modified dynamically.

Comment: @fahadash yes, that's a question

Comment: And there's your answer. The `.css()` is added inline and therefore changes the HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is the proper behavior html() gives you innerHTML property which changes when you modify the object dynamically (Not sure about all browsers but for Chrome).

.text() is giving you innerText which does not include attributes so your length doesn't change.